# 5-day training in NYC

Tags: visas, new-york-city, study

I have a tourist visa in the US and was planning to return months from now, but it will be just for 2 weeks. 1 week vacation and I have seen a course in coursehorse.com for application development which runs for just 5 days. Do I need a separate student visa just for a 5-day course? Will they require it when I enroll? I have sent an email to the course site, but I didn't get any response. I hope I can get an answer from here.

Comment: So you're planning to travel to the US once only, for two weeks?  And you're asking if you can use the tourist visa for tourism and taking the course?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casual study in the USA](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18898/casual-study-in-the-usa)

Comment: Hi @jpatokal, Yes that's right. I have read in the embassy site that I can use tourist visa for study but only in a short recreational course of study (ex: art class, music, cooking class )and not for credit towards a degree. However, I have read as well that schools/course providers don't mind what your visa status is as long as you will pay. Besides, it's only a 5-day certification course and not towards a degree although it can add up value to my resume/ CV. I'm so not sure how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tourist visa enables you to come and visit whenever you like. At the port of entry you will get the 6 month visa usually enabling you to stay in the country for 6 months at a stretch. I checked out coursehero, it would depend on the course you are taking but courses there seem to be adhoc and open for all to sign up. Thus they may not need the visa requirement (Unsure how will they check that requirement) If they allowed you to sign up without the requirement then does not seem to me that they would need a student visa just for that. 
Your best bet is contacting the course folks directly rather than coursehero.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! I did contact coursehorse.com and they said the courses they offer are all general and public programs so student visa is not required. You are right I should contact the course provider itself to verify as well. Coz I wonder what ID will I present when I get to the class in case they require? passport probably?

Comment: I am glad it helped, you can chose this as the right answer if this helped :) Have a nice trip